# Mocking MockHttpServletRequest object gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletConnection

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, jmockit

I have a Controller

```
@RestController
public class BodyController extends BaseController {

@Autowired
private BodyService bodyService;

@PostMapping(value = "/api/body")

@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Body Created", content = {
    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ReadBodyDto.class))}),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json")),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized access", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json")),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "409", description = "Conflict"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "412", description = "Precondition mismatched"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error")})

    @Operation(summary = "Body", requestBody = @RequestBody(description = "The Body that will be created.", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = BodyDto.class))))

    @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createBody(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody BodyDto bodyDto,
                                            HttpServletRequest request) {
        handleJWT(request, false);

        LOGGER.info(bodyDto.toString());

        BodyValidator.validateBody(bodyDto);

        Message<?> bodyResponse = bodyService.createBody(bodyDto, getToken());

        return constructResponseEntity(bodyDto);
    }
    
}
```

Using the jMockit testing framework I need to write a Unit test and Integration test for this Controller Class.

I tried to add request Object using org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest but getting error as below :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletConnection at
> com.package.BodyControllerTest$2.(BodyControllerTest.java:94) at
> com.package.BodyControllerTest.createBody(BodyControllerTest.java:93)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> jakarta.servlet.ServletConnection at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

This is my Test Class

```
class BodyControllerTest {

    protected String accessToken;
    protected ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity;
    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;
    protected JsonNode createBody;
    
    
    /**


     * @Tested will specify the class is under testing
     */
    @Tested
    private BodyController bodyController;
    
    
    /**
     * @Capturing will create mocked instances of each and every new object of that particular class
     * and also
     * will extend its reach to every subclass extending or implementing the annotated field's type
     */
    
    
    /**
     * @Injectable only one mocked instance will be created
     */
    @Injectable
    private JwtModel jwtModel;
    
    @Injectable
    private BodyService bodyService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        accessToken = "//confidential";
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        responseEntity = null;
        request = null;
    }

    @Test
    void createBody() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File fileObj = new File(classLoader.getResource("request/create-body.json").getFile());
        // use try-catch block to convert JSON data into Map

        Map<String, Object> createBodyData;
        try {
            // read JSON data from file using fileObj and map it using ObjectMapper and TypeReference classes
            createBodyData = JsonUtility.MAPPER.readValue(
                    fileObj, new TypeReference<>() {
                    });

            createBody = JsonUtility.MAPPER.convertValue(createBodyData, JsonNode.class);
            String contentType = "application/json";

            new Expectations() {{
                request = new MockHttpServletRequest(); // This line give above error
                request.setServerName("localhost");
                request.setServerPort(8080);
                request.setRequestURI("/api/body");
                request.setContent(createBody.binaryValue());
                request.setContentType(contentType);
                request.setMethod("POST");
                request.addHeader("Content-type", contentType);
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            }};

            responseEntity = bodyController.createBody(JsonUtility.MAPPER.convertValue(createBody, BodyDto.class), request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Add your dependencies. Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the dependency management done by the starters or mixing different/incompatible versions of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

The class `jakarta.servlet.ServletConnection` was added in Servlet 6.0. From `MockHttpServletRequest` javadoc :

> As of Spring 6.0, this set of mocks is designed on a Servlet 6.0
> baseline.

If you're using Maven you might need to declare this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
  <!-- Mark as provided if the servlet jar is provided by the application server -->
  <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

You can check for your dependencies using the command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```